# C# Выделение ячеек в Excel Unable to get the Select property of the Range class

Tags: c#, excel

Стала падать программа. В ней реализовано так:
`((Range)worksheet.Cells[2, 1]).Select();`
Падает с ошибкой

> Unable to get the Select property of the Range class

Все мои попытки исправить были тщетны. 
Интернет говорил

> The sheet must be active before you can select a range on it.

Но на `worksheet.Select();` тоже падает. 
Как восстановить функционал? Офис установлен 2013.

Comment: *на worksheet.Select(); тоже падает* - книга-родитель должна быть активна.

Comment: @vikttur добавил `worksheet.Activate();  worksheet.Select();` получил `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC` на `worksheet.Select()`

Comment: *книга-родитель должна быть активна* - *workbook* где-то фигурирует? А само приложение *Excel*?

Comment: ни  чего не выходит. ощущение, что у Range не существует методов Select и Activate

Comment: Нашел на одном из форумов. Заменил на `Range cells = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[2, 1]]; worksheet.Application.Goto(cells, true);` Работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменил

```
((Range)worksheet.Cells[2, 1]).Select();
```

на

```
Range cells = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[1, 1], worksheet.Cells[2, 1]]; 
worksheet.Application.Goto(cells, true);
```

Работает